# Why did standing on one's feet become the posture for prayer?

Tags: tefilla, history, shemoneh-esrei

When one reads about people praying to G-d throughout Tanac"h, we rarely discover them standing to pray. Most of the time they are kneeling, prostrating or falling on their faces. We see that when Moshe prayed, he fell on his face (See [Bemidbar 14:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=168), [Bemidbar 16:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=206) for two of many examples.)

In [Daniel 6:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14260&st=&pgnum=56), we see that he faced Jerusalem and prayed 3 times daily in a kneeling position. The 3 times daily prayer facing Jerusalem looks like the closest "imitation" to our current *Amidah* (in terms of facing Jerusalem.)

There are some exceptions. Regarding Avraham it says, "He was still **standing** before G-d.' ([Breishit 18:22](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=234))

The Gemarah pretty consistently says that prayer (generally, in the Gemarah, the term *tefilla* usually means the *Amidah* aka "Shemoneh Eseh") should be done standing. See Mishnah Bavli [Brachot 3:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=22b&format=pdf) and [Brachot 5:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=30b&format=pdf) which both use the term "standing".

At what point and why did the posture change to standing?

Comment: Maybe it started with Avraham... Do you mean to ask why Chazal went with Avraham's method and not Daniyel's?

Comment: Maybe it says "So-and-so prostrated himself and said…" precisely because that wasn't the usual posture for prayer.

Comment: Aren’t there different types of tefillah? We also “fall on our faces,” but tachanun is a different kind of tefillah from s”e.

Comment: I think it has everything to do with what is proper conduct in front of a king.

Comment: @DonielF Indeed, there are different forms. I agree that there is a bit of vagueness in my question but not intentionally. When the Gemarrah mentions *tefilla* it generally means Shemoneh Esreh. Of course, within Tanac"h, there is no concept of "Shemoneh Esreh". So, one can conjecture what various people were praying. Nonetheless, I think that the quote from Daniel seems the closest to the idea of Shemoneh Esreh that we currently have. And, there, we see that he knelt. If you have any suggestions on how I can improve the question so that it's better focused, I appreciate it.

Comment: @ezra I found a Google Book source that discusses this topic, in general, which inspired the question. Indeed, it does mention that factor. So, your hunch is prob. correct. However, it seems to beg the question as to why people like Moshe and Daniel didn't stand. Perhaps what DonielF hints to is that there might be different required postures for different types of prayer. That might be a major factor in answering this.

Comment: @DanF Or perhaps in the times of Moshe and Daniel, one was supposed to kneel before a king, whereas during Roman times (in which Chazal lived) standing was the procedure.

Comment: @ezra You may be on to something, here.

Answer (score 3):

[Ma'aseh Rokeach to Hilchot Tefillah 5:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Maaseh_Rokeach_on_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.5.2?lang=bi) writes that a source for the requirement to stand during prayer is the concept of:

> אין שירות אלא מעומד
>
> The [priestly Temple] service was only performed while standing

(mentioned in [Sotah 38a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.38a.5?lang=bi)).

My understanding of his comment is that our prayers today are modelled (to an extent) on the Temple service. We therefore stand to pray, as the priests stood to serve in the Temple.

Comment: Thanks for noticing and answering this question! I'll check out the content in the link, later. Offhand, though, what you mentioned seems to contradict Daniel's posture.

Comment: Fair point. Although, of course, Daniel was post-first temple. Maybe the rabbinic enactment to stand only came about after the second temple was destroyed.